# Restrict html tags to get saved

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a text area where writing any text and making it bold italic is adding adding extra html tags when saving data to the data base which apparently breaks the screen because from screen I insert only 2000 words but when saving it becomes may be 2010 or 2030 by adding additional tags.

Can anyone help in letting mw know as to how can I restrict these tags being saved.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Comment: Why is your screen restricted to use only 2000 words? What if all 2000 of them are very long? Why are the HTML tags counted in this approach, while not all of them need additional space when being rendered?